# ES6/TypeScript way to generate a polyline from an array

Tags: svg, typescript, polyline

I want to generate several SVG polylines from a structure that I have:

```
data = [item0, item1, ...., item50]
item0 = {y1: 10, y2: 100, ...[other properties]...}
item1 = {y1: 1000, y2: 50, ...}
item2 = {y1: 500, y2: 40, ...}
```

So the structure is an array of items where one item has multiple Y values.
The x value is determined by iterating over the structure (x*10).

The output should be a string for each "y", like this: "x0,y1[0] x1,y1[1] x2,y1[2]..."

```
polyLine1 = "0,10 10,100 20,500..."
polyLine2 = "0,1000 10,50 20,40 ..."
```

I can do it with underscore.js or something similar like this:

```
polyLine1 = "";
_.each (data, function(item, index){
    polyLine1 += "" + index*10 + "," + item.y1
}
polyLine2 = "";
_.each (data, function(item, index){
    polyLine2 += "" + index*10 + "," + item.y2
}
```

What I'm looking for is a smarter way to initialize a complete output structure using lambda/arrow syntax:

```
this.polyLines = {
    polyLine1 = ...,// iterate data, pick y1 property, map x and y, reduce/join to a string
    polyLine2 = ...,
}
```

For reference, I'm using TypeScript with Ionic2 (Angular2).
I know I can do this with template bindings (which would be probably slower and less readable) but I'm just looking to learn.

Comment: Is there any way you could show some real data? I would expect something more like `data = [{y1: 10, y2: 100}, {y1: 11, y2: 101}]`, and then what exactly that should produce, because you say at first you want a string, but then you have this `lines` structure...

Comment: I'm getting a few ADC values from a board through serial, each second or so. These range from 0 to 1024. I want to display the last 50 of those on a chart. Lines means polylines, one for each ADC input.

Comment: Going meta here but I don't understand why anyone would downvote this. It's a question of converting some 'old' underscore.js code style into a newer lambda-based style. The svg and polylines tags were suggested edits which I approved.

Comment: I don't see any downvotes on this question, by the way. I have enough rep to be able to see the split, and it says 0 upvotes and 0 downvotes. Well, now it says one upvote since you've included more info about inputs and outputs :).

Comment: Sorry, I thought that initially all questions start with 1 vote, probably confusing SO with some other site :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This produces what I think you're looking for. Basically, [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) (from ES5.1) is what you want. I'm using lambdas ([arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)) and [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) from ES6, along with [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) and [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) from ES5.1.

```js
let data = [{
  y1: 10,
  y2: 100
}, {
  y1: 1000,
  y2: 50
}]
let keyReduction = (b) => Object.keys(b).reduce((c, d, x) => c += `${x*10} ${b[d]} `, "");
let polyLines = data.reduce((a, b, i) => {
  a[`polyLine${i+1}`] = keyReduction(b).trim();
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(JSON.stringify(polyLines))
```

I'm not sure if those will work for polylines, as I've not done any SVG, but I'm sure you can tweak it to fit your needs.

Looks like you need commas. You can do the same code, but with a comma:

```js
let data = [{
  y1: 10,
  y2: 100
}, {
  y1: 1000,
  y2: 50
}]
let keyReduction = (b) => Object.keys(b).reduce((c, d, x) => c += `${x*10},${b[d]} `, "");
let polyLines = data.reduce((a, b, i) => {
  a[`polyLine${i+1}`] = keyReduction(b).trim();
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(JSON.stringify(polyLines))
```

Here's another example, breaking out each property name into a separate property of the final output:

```js
let data = [{
  y1: 10,
  y2: 100
}, {
  y1: 1000,
  y2: 50
}]
let polyLines = data.reduce((a, b, i) => {
  Object.keys(b).forEach((k) => {
    a[k] = (a[k] || "") + (i * 10) + "," + b[k] + " ";
    });
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(JSON.stringify(polyLines))
```

Comment: Wow, that's great, more than I could ask for. I wasn't looking to process all subfields automatically but it's a nice trick to have in the bag.

Comment: I edited the question rather than provide a comment here. The code you provided is nice but doesn't do what I want, it was my mistake how the requirement was formulated. If you'd be so kind as to provide an alternative answer I would be grateful. I created a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/42b8uown/ with some real data, but there might be issues with how typescript is implemented there.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what's up with the TypeScript there. If you look at the rendered JavaScript, it's like it's half done: `acc[(``polyLine${ + line)] = i + },${ + item.sensorValue;`

Comment: I've added an example without template literals, and added a fork of your fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/6cw9ee4k/1/ which seems to work.

Comment: Thank you. Please see my 3 revision ( https://jsfiddle.net/42b8uown/3/ ) and the comment at the end and the edit in the OP.

Comment: I've updated the last example. I think you should be able to go from here, as I've actually got paying work to do now :).